# CSS href text link jumps to a new line when clicked

Tags: css, hyperlink

My navigation bar works perfectly fine, any image links work fine, but all text links on my page jump down when I click on them. Most of them jump so far you cannot actually click it.

I also noticed my `a:visited` links are inheriting the color `#000` from somewhere, when they should be `#616161`. There is no issue when browsing on my Android device, but happens in IE11 and Chrome32.

The HTML is nothing special. Just

```
<a href="/page-name.html">Page Name</a>
```

type links. It has to be something with the CSS.

The CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:    #7296d9;
    max-width:1000px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:auto;
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin:4px;
}
#content {
    width:98%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
#paragraph {
    width:80%;
    font-size:18px;
    color:    #666;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:10px auto 25px auto;
}
.reviews {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:justify;
    color:    #666;
}
p {
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
}
h1 {
    line-height:48px;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
}
h2 {
    line-height:42px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color:     #616161;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color:     #ffffff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#header {
    height:86px;
    max-height:86px;
    width:98%;
    min-width:500px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#header .left {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
#header .media-header {
    float:right;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-right:-20px;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu {
    display:table;
    width:100%;        
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(    #d5d5d5,     #595959); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(    #d5d5d5,     #595959); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(    #d5d5d5,     #595959); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(    #d5d5d5,     #595959); /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul {
    height:auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px     #cccccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: table-row;
}
#menu a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:     #000000;
    padding: 8px auto 8px auto;
}
#menu a:hover, a:active {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:     #fff;
}
#menu ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    width:auto;
}
#menu ul a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    color:    #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul a:hover, a:active {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:     #fff;
}
#menu ul ul {
    background:     #999;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul ul li {
    width:auto;
    border-top: 1px solid     #ccc;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:left;
    color:    #000;
}        
#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    color:    #FFF;
}
#menu ul ul:last-child, nav ul ul:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.center {
    text-align:center;
}
#reviews {
    width:80%;
    text-align:justify;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:25px auto 25px auto;
}
#reviews img {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#form {
    color:    #666;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    width:350px;
}
#form p {
    color:    #666;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    width:350px;
}
.bottombar {
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
#footer {
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    color:    #616161;
    text-align:center;
    width:auto;
    margin:5px auto 5px auto;
}
#footer img {
    text-align:center;
    color:    #616161;
    width:100%;
    margin:5px auto 5px auto;
}
#media-footer {
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0 15px 55px;
}
#media-footer img {
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0 15px 55px;
}
nav ul {
    display:none;
}
#minimenu {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are adding padding to the element when it is `:active`:

```
#menu ul a:hover, a:active {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

It's worth noting that you are repeating the same styling in different instances.

```
#menu a:hover, a:active {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Just remove the padding from both declarations and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I read your suggestion and thought "AH-HAH!!" Unfortunately, it still does it. I removed padding from everything I could, but had to keep it on the #menu{} tag or it shrank my nav bar (removed temporarily to test). If you check out the page, the link in the middle "TEST TEST TEST" no longer jumps in IE, but still does in Chrome, and further down, the "Angie's List" "Contact Us" "Terms of Use" etc... all those links still do in both browsers.

Comment: @MakoHunter Actually, you would remove `display:block` too. That was causing it to break to a new line. The 'test test test' `p` element isn't an issue. I didn't notice you were referring to the 'angie list` element

Comment: I jumped for joy for a minute. It worked for IE, but still breaking in Chrome.

Comment: @MakoHunter Are you sure nothing is being cached? I'm on the page and it works in Chrome.

Comment: F12 clear cache and hard reload. Still doing it. Let me try from a different computer real quick.

Comment: Okay, something with the cache on this computer then. My laptop is displaying it properly now. Thank you Josh. You have been a lot of help!